# UISegmentedContol: reverse tintColor and backgroundColor

Tags: ios, swift, uisegmentedcontrol, tintcolor

I have UISegmentedControl that I add a few white images on transparent background to.

```
for (index,element) in ELEMENTS.enumerate() {
    segmentedControl.insertSegmentWithImage(element.logo, atIndex: index, animated: false)
}
```

Segments not selected now have the background color set to segmentedControl.backgroundColor, and the image is colored with segmentedControl.tintColor. The selected segment is reversed, with the background set to .tintColor, and the image colored with the .backgroundColor.

This works fine, but I would like it to be the other way around: That the selected segment has a image colored with .tintColor, and background colored .backgroundColor.

I know I can achieve this by just switching the colors in code, but I'm using

```
let sharedApplication = UIApplication.sharedApplication()
sharedApplication.delegate?.window??.tintColor = newColor
```

in the app to change the tintColor of all the views in the app, so it would be nice if this would result in the color being changed the way I want it in my segmented control.

Any ideas?

Comment: You can change tint color only for this control by setting  `UISegmentedControl.tintColor`.

Comment: Yes, but then I would have to do the sharedApplication.delegate?.window??.tintColor = newColor and UISegmentedControl.tintColor = newColor every time, right?

Comment: No. You use ` sharedApplication.delegate?.window??.tintColor = newColor` to set global tint color only one time. And you use `UISegmentedControl.tintColor` every time when you want to set custom tint color for this control. Also you can try to use `UISegmentedControl.appearance().tintColor` to set custom tint color for all segmented controls in your application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use `UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate?.window??.tintColor` to set global tint color that is used by all controls of your application.

You can use `UISegmentedControl.appearance().tintColor` to set custom tint color for all segmented controls in your application.

And you can use `UISegmentedControl.tintColor` to set custom tint color for specific segmented control.

To switch background and tint colors for all segmented controls in your application:

```
UISegmentedControl.appearance().tintColor = backgroundColor
UISegmentedControl.appearance().backgroundColor = tintColor
```